# How do I configure vim to open zip files?

Tags: linux, vim, gzip, war

I have several systems that use Vim, and on one I am unable to view/edit zipped files. I believe I have the right plugins because my other system with Vim 7.0 works correctly with the same plugins.

I get an error:

```
$ vi admin.war
~
...
~
***error*** (zip#Browse) unzip not available on your system
```

My machine:

```
$ uname -srmo
Linux 2.6.35.4-rscloud x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ vim --v
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.2 (2008 Aug 9, compiled Sep 28 2010 11:05:08)

$ find / -name "*zip*.vim"
/usr/share/vim/vim72/autoload/zip.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim72/autoload/gzip.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim72/plugin/gzip.vim
```

Comment: is the actual unzip package installed on that machine?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

All you need to do install unzip, and it will work.

Comment: @mhausler: If this answer solved your problem you might want to accept it.

Comment: This worked for me on Windows as well, by installing GnuWin32 unzip.

Comment: If you plan on modifying a file within the zip file, you also need to install zip.

Answer (score 0):

according to [vim 7.2+](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/autoload/zip.vim) natural autoload method, an unzip package is required:

```
"  Global Values: {{{1
if !exists("g:zip_shq")
 if &shq != ""
  let g:zip_shq= &shq
 elseif has("unix")
  let g:zip_shq= "'"
 else
  let g:zip_shq= '"'
 endif
endif
if !exists("g:zip_zipcmd")
 let g:zip_zipcmd= "zip"
endif
if !exists("g:zip_unzipcmd")
 let g:zip_unzipcmd= "unzip"
endif
if !exists("g:zip_extractcmd")
 let g:zip_extractcmd= g:zip_unzipcmd
endif
```